# A tricky integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find the exact value of $$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{\arctan{(x^2)} }{1+x^2} \, dx$$

Ostensibly, I'd want to use this: $$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan{(x)}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

But either I'm missing something, or this doesn't work out nicely ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

\begin{align}
u & = \frac 1 x \\[8pt]
du & = \frac{-dx}{x^2} \\[8pt]
\frac{-du}{u^2} & = dx
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I = & \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{\arctan(x^2)}{1+x^2} \, dx \\[10pt]
= & \int_\sqrt{3}^{1/\sqrt{3}} \frac{\arctan\frac{1}{u^2}}{1+\left(\frac{1}{u^2}\right)} \left(\frac{-du}{u^2}\right) \\[10pt]
= & \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\sqrt{3} \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{u^2}\right)}{u^2+1} \,du \\[10pt]
= & \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\sqrt{3} \frac{\frac\pi2 - \arctan(u^2)}{u^2+1} \,du \\[10pt]
= & \frac \pi 2 \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\sqrt{3} \frac{du}{1+u^2} - \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\sqrt{3} \frac{\arctan(u^2)}{1+u^2} \,du \\[10pt]
= & \frac \pi 2 \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^\sqrt{3} \frac{du}{1+u^2} - I.
\end{align}

So we have
$$
I = \left(\int\cdots\cdots\cdots\right) - I,
$$
whence
$$
2I = \left(\int\cdots\cdots\cdots\right).
$$
That last integral is routine.  Remember that $\arctan\sqrt{3} = \pi/3$ and $\arctan(1/\sqrt{3})= \pi/6$.

Comment: bingo! nicely done. +1

Comment: @BennettGardiner : Thank you.

Comment: This is clever, thank you! How did you think to use $u=1/x$? Is this a general method, or a fancy trick?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee The transformation is strongly suggested by the limits of integration.

Comment: In hindsight, of course, it makes sense :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee : It reminded me of a problem I'd seen before, although I don't recall the precise details.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee : To be a bit more explicit: The bounds of integration are each other's reciprocals, so that's a hint that $u=1/x$ is something to think about.  Next, I know that the reciprocal of a random variable with a standard Cauchy distribution also has a standard Cauchy distribution.  The Cauchy distribution is the probability distribution $(\text{constant}\cdot dx)/(1+x^2)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And the fact that $\arctan(1/z) + \arctan(z) =\pi/2$ if $z>0$.

Comment: Those three things allowed @MichaelHardy to knock this one out of the park!

Comment: How about mine? Is it good? :D

Comment: My favorite part of this answer is how you saw that those two integrals with different variables of integration are equal. +1

Answer (score 21):

Use the substitution $x=\tan\theta$ to obtain:
$$I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \arctan(\tan^2\theta)\,d\theta $$
Since
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\,dx$$
We get:
$$I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \arctan(\cot^2\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \text{arccot}(\tan^2\theta)\,d\theta$$
Add the two to get:
$$2I=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/3} \frac{\pi}{2}\,d\theta \Rightarrow I=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$$
....which well agrees with Wolfram Alpha.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you [Pranav Arora](https://brilliant.org/profile/pranav-zt2nnf/feed/) on brilliant.org? :)

Comment: Hello Fey! Yes, I am the same person, its been a long time you visited us there. Are you busy these days? Your Calculus problems were awesome, do visit again. :)

Comment: Not that busy, I just feel disappointed there. I'll return but not in the near future. In the meantime, I'll have fun here. I,m glad you enjoy my calculus problems. :) Anyway, I wonder how come $\arctan (\cot^2\theta)+\text{arccot}(\tan^2\theta)=\dfrac\pi2$? Are sure about that identity?

Comment: Ah, ok. :)

I didn't use the identity you mention, I used $\arctan(\tan^2\theta)+\text{arccot}(\tan^2\theta)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: This is very clever; I didn't know that identity. Thanks!

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see that. +1 then. :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I used the same identity as Micheal Hardy.